# Overload [] C++ operator for complex data-structure

Tags: c++, indexing, operator-overloading

what I plan to do: I have a own container-structure. But it should not store all elements, but only some with special properties, while others can be created dynamically from the information in the stucture.

Thus I have a insert(ITEM* i) method, that checks, whether i needs to be stored explicitly and is then stored into a map, or of it can be reconstructed dynamically. Then only the information that the item was added is stored.

The same for a ITEM* get(ITEMINDEX idx) method. It checks whether the ITEM belonging to idx is stored explicitly. If yes, it is read from the internal map and the pointer returned. If it is registered, but implicitly stored, the ITEM is created dynamically and returned.

In order to be compatible with other structures in the code, I planned to overload the [] operator, but I don't know how to approach this or if this is even possible for this more complex structure.

Is it possible and if yes, how?
Thanks in advance!

**Update**
Nims code works. But I recognised a problem now (although it was obvious from the beginning...): If get() finds a entry the pointer is returned by []. If it is not stored, the ITEM is constructed and the pointer returned. But the RAM is never released, because the algorithm that uses the container cannot distinguish between saved an constructed ITEMS to delete the second kind.

Comment: I would imagine the easiest would be for `operator[]` to return `get(index)`.

Comment: Hi Nim,
yes this seems to work. But I recognised a problem now (although it was obvious...): If get finds a entry the pointer is returned. If not the ITEM is constructed and the pointer returned. But the RAM is never released, because the algorithm that uses the container cannot distinguish between saved an constructed ITEMS to delete the second kind.

Comment: @user3572032 have you considered using smart pointers instead of bare ones? ie. unique_ptr<>.

Comment: I will try marcin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to provide operator[] for your object you have to answer your self if following code makes sense:

```
      MyObj obj;
/*1*/ obj[some_index] = new_object;
/*2*/ Obj& some_object = obj[some_index];
```

what semantics would be for case `1` - you say: it should insert some value into your class but, you add new data with `insert(ITEM* i)` (no some_index provided here), so you should prohibit usage of your class as in case of `1`.

Now for case `2`, in your example you show that `ITEM* get(ITEMINDEX idx)`, so your class client code must know what is ITEMINDEX, so it looks like case `2` would be ok.

The problem is IMO only with case 1, and inserting new data with operator[]. If you look at the `std::map` container then you have no problem with both above cases. Users of you class will want to use it in similar way to `std::map` operator[], if its functionality will differ it will cause confusion.

Comment: Hi Marcin,
yes the case 2 is the interesting one, since I use the other containers in most cases in this way and can change the inserts with appropriate function calls, if the read access works.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ class operator is a method with a weird name. It can do whatever you wish, provided it has the expected weird name. In the case of operator [], it looks like

```
template <typename T>
T& operator[](std::size_t idx)       { /* arbitrary code */ };
```

That's about all there is to it really.

This interface is quite constrained. You'll get an index and need to produce a reference to an instance of your class in response. You can return a reference to something with unusual ideas about assignment, e.g. on assignment it does some checking with a data structure accessed via an internal pointer. There may be a lot of incidental complexity down this path.